# Does $(n + 1)$ divide infinitely often the concatenation of the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, \dots, n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For each positive integer $n$, let $C(n)$ be the concatenation of the first $n$ integers, so that, for example, $C(8)$ is $12345678$.

I am trying to establish whether $C(n)$ is divisible infinitely often by $n$?

Any ideas?

Comment: By $n$ or $n+1$? $1234...10^k$ is divisible by $10^k$.

Comment: What are your own ideas?

Comment: If by $\ n+1\ $ is meant, the first solutions are : $$[2, 8, 26, 68, 1052, 1598, 2510, 8166]$$

Comment: @Peter i.e. [OEIS:A110740](https://oeis.org/A110740)$-1$

Comment: Side-note : Those numbers are called Smarandache-numbers and a famous problem is whether such a number can be prime.

Comment: The naive probabilistic heuristic (that it happens with probability $1/(n+1)$) suggests that there are indeed infinitely many examples. Local considerations for primes dividing $10(10-1)(10+1)$ would presumably only change the heuristic by a constant factor.

Comment: @GregMartin But in some cases the divisibility cannot hold , for example if $n$ is odd. Do you think that we can nevertheless apply it ?

Comment: @player3236 OEIS strikes again :) I can stop my calculations then.

Comment: @Peter I wouldn't have found the sequence without your initial calculations.

Comment: @Peter: that's what I meant by "local considerations", at finitely many primes like 2.